# Mercurial managing multiple repositories

Tags: mercurial

We have a repository `myproject` - as the repo is nearly ready for release we are creating `myproject-1_0`.  Version 2 dev will continue in `myproject` while minor tweaks and bug fixes will go in  `myproject-1_0`.   What is the best way to merge `myproject-1_0` changes into  `myproject`?

Is this the best approach:

```
$ cd myproject
$ hg pull ../myproject-1_0
$ hg merge
$ hg commit -m 'Merge bugfix from 1.0 branch'
$ hg push
```

?

What would happen if we did this merge on Feb 1st, then we made more changes in `myproject-1_0`?  Would we follow the steps again and the `hg pull ../myproject-1_0` would just pull the changesets done after the pull on Feb 1st?

In the `myproject` repo, is there a way to do an `hg log` and determine which changesets came from `myproject-1_0` and which ones came from `myproject`?

Are there any other recommendations about this general approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions in sequence:

- Is this the best approach? - **yes**, unless you want to use named branches and keep everything in one repository
- would just pull the changesets done after the pull on Feb 1st? - **yes**
- is there a way to do an `hg log` and determine which changesets came from `myproject-1_0`? - **no**

Unfortunately, unless you start mucking about with named branches, changesets that originate in the other repository looks no different from the ones in your main repository.

Comment: @Marcus: And in case you decide for *named branches* (to have a **yes** for the third question), you might want to read [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1405604/151299).

Comment: @Oben, yep, that seems like a good workflow if you want to use named branches.

Answer (score 4):

So this is what Mercurial is designed to do

I would suggest taking a look at http://www.hginit.com. But what you're asking if when you pull changes will it only pull the changes since the last pull, yes. You can't tell which changesets came from a different clone though, only user names are tracked in the idea that you are thinking about.

If you want to know where things are coming from this is something you can do in commit messages.

Comment: Good suggestion re hginit.com - great tuturoial