# mercurial set a branch as the new default branch

Tags: mercurial, branch, clone

The result I would need is that when cloning a repository the code is at the last revision of a branch that is not the default branch, with no need to do "hg update mybranchname".
Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424377/make-another-branch-default

Comment: you're right, the question at the link above is the same of mine. I'm sorry I searched in google but didn't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The advice until now has been: you should [always use `default` as your main branch](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching#What_not_to_do) since Mercurial will checkout `default` if it finds it in the repository.

This changes a little with Mercurial 2.1: you can now close the `default` branch (if you have one) and add a bookmark named `default` in its place. A new clone will retrieve the bookmark and update to it, effectively switching to another branch in the process.

Note that it's your responsibility to keep the `default` bookmark pointing to the head of the branch you want to checkout, so this is not 100% fool proof.

Answer (score 2):

You could merge the branch into the default branch, like:

```
hg merge mybranchname
hg commit
```

Now the branch is in effect the main branch.  You can hide the old branch with:

```
hg update mybranchname
hg commit --close-branch
```

Comment: so the only way is to merge from the default branch, I cannot leave many branches and set a custom branch as the new default branch?

Comment: Hmm, you can `clone -b mybranchname http://repo.url localdir` to start with "mybranchname" checked out.  I don't think there's a way to make "tip" point to another branch, since "tip" is a real branch itself.

Comment: @Andomar - tip isn't branch, but special bookpark, FYI

Comment: my target is that a user clones all the repos without parameters, and in all repos after cloning he targets the version I want (latest in a branch). I can see the only way to obtain this result is through merge from not default branches to the default branch. thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

By default default branch is not "default", but branch from tip.

Just commit before clone-pull to any existing branch.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your answer

Comment: You always commit to the **branch of tip changeset** (if not up before commit to another branch), not to "default" branch

Comment: I already committed hundreds of times on a branch that I would like to become the default branch. I understand this is possible only through a merge to the default branch

Comment: I can't see how this answer relates to the question, nor what it means.